# Reflection principle in the proof of the distribution of $M_t - W_t$ (Brownian motion)

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be the Brownian motion starting at $0$.  Consider the following random variables. $M_t = \sup_{0\leq s \leq t} W_s$ and $|W_t|$.

We first calculate

$$\Bbb{P}(|W_t|>a ) = \Bbb{P}(W_t >a)  + \Bbb{P}(W_t< -a)$$

Fact: The random variable $M_t - W_t$ has the same distribution of $|W_t|$.

I was thinking, is there a way of proving that

$$\Bbb{P}(M_t - W_t >a) = \Bbb{P}(W_t >a) + \Bbb{P}(W_t <-a) $$

using the reflexion principle?

**Attempt:** The event $$[M_t-W_t >a] = [M_t-W_t >a, W_t\geq - a] \cup [M_t-W_t >a, W_t< - a] = [M_t-W_t >a, W_t\geq - a] \cup [ W_t< - a]. $$

What I am trying to do is to prove (using some sort of reflexion principle) that $$\Bbb{P}(M_t-W_t >a, W_t\geq - a) = \Bbb{P}(W_t >a)$$

Edit:

The reflexion principle is given by $$P^0[W_t \leq a \mid \mathcal{F}_{T_b}] = P^0[W_t \geq 2b-a \mid \mathcal{F}_{T_b}] \text{ on } \{T_b \leq t\} $$

where $T_b = \inf \{t \geq 0 , W_t = b\}$

Comment: Could you add the reflection principle to your question (the version you know/want to use)...?

Comment: @saz, I edited the question.